# Select single column value as livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

As the title indicates I'm trying to select a single column from my database as livedata. But I'm getting the following error message.

`error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.lang.Float>)`

I'm tracking the phones location and insert location objects into a table called LocationEntity.

My entity looks as the following

```
data class LocationEntity(
...
    val speed: Float,
...
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0
)
```

My DAO looks as the following

```
private const val ACCURACY_THRESHOLD = 50
private const val speedSql = """
    SELECT speed
    FROM LocationEntity
    WHERE runId = :runId AND accuracy < $ACCURACY_THRESHOLD
    ORDER BY dateTime
    DESC LIMIT 1
"""

@Dao
interface LocationDao {
...
    @Query(speedSql)
    suspend fun speed(runId: Long): LiveData<Float>
}
```

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Thanks for chipping in but it turned out to be the combination of suspend and LiveData

Comment: oh yeah, I should have noticed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suspend and LiveData doesn't work together. The below works.

```
@Dao
interface LocationDao {
...
    @Query(speedSql)
    fun speed(runId: Long): LiveData<Float>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think LiveData works out of the box, there's no reason to use Coroutines when returning LiveData.

When using LiveData it already handles it on a background thread. When NOT using LiveData then in that case you can use Coroutines (and maybe eventually Coroutines Channels) or RxJava etc.

You may find something about insert data by using livedata in [google codelab](http://%20https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin.)

The most interesting part is the code below

```kotlin
@Dao
interface WordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    fun getAllWords(): LiveData<List<Word>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    fun deleteAll()
}

class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao) {

    val allWords: LiveData<List<Word>> = wordDao.getAllWords()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(word: Word) {
        wordDao.insert(word)
    }
}
```